# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ in $\lim_{x\to -2}$

Tags: calculus

$$
\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{x^3+ ax+b}{x+2}= 2
$$

Find the value of $a$ and $b$.

I don't know how to solve this question. But I know the answer is $a=-10$, $b=-12$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Since the numerator has to become 0 when -2 is put in, my guess is that x+2 from the numerator would be simplified out with the x+2 from the denominator. You would be able to get the relationship between a and b by putting in -2 in the numerator. Then, after x+2 is canceled out, you just have to plug in -2 and get another equation regarding the relationship between a and b. Since you have two equations, you just have to solve the system and get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: in order for the limit to exist and be finite, the limit is going to have to take the indeterminate form $\frac00$. L'Hopital's rule will help from there.

Answer (score 2):

Divide $\frac{x^3+ax+b}{x+2}=x^2-2x+(a+4)+\frac{b-2(a+4)}{x+2}$

In order for the limit to exist you will need $b-2(a+4)=0$, otherwise the last fraction diverges, while the polynomial in front converges making the whole limit to diverge.

Finally, since you need the limit to be $2$, then you need $2=\lim_{x\to-2}(x^2-2x+(a+4))=a+12$.

It follows that $a=-10$, and from $b-2(a+4)=0$, you get that $b=-12$.

Answer (score 1):

The denominator, x+ 2, becomes 0 when x= -2 so, in order that the limit exist, the numerator must also be 0 at x= -2.  The numerator must be of the form $(x+ 2)(x^2+ px+ q)$.  In that case, for x NOT -2, we have $\frac{x^3+ ax+ b}{x+ 2}= \frac{(x+2)(x^2+ px+ q)}{x+ 2}= x^2+ px+ q$.  And, at x= -2, that must be $4- 2p+ q= 2$ so that $2p- q= 2$.

Now, $(x+ 2)(x^2+ px+ q)= x^3+ px^2+ qx+ 2x^2+ 2px+ 2q= x^3+ (p+ 2)x^2+ (2p+ q)x+ 2q= x^3+ ax+ b$

so we  must have p+ 2= 0, 2p+ q= a, and 2q= b.  From "$p+ 2= 0$" we have p= -2.  From $2p- q= -4- q= 2$, we have q= -6.  a= 2p+ q= -4- 6= -10 and b= 2q= -12.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the limit to exist, we must have that $x^3+ax+b$ is divisible by $x+2$. If this wasn't the case, we would see that as $x\rightarrow -2$, $x^3+ax+b\rightarrow c$ for some value $c$ while $x+2\rightarrow 0$, and so the limit would not be defined. So, the question remaining is to find $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $x+2\vert x^3+ax+b$. To find $a$, we can apply L'Hopital's rule to say that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow-2}(\frac{3x^2+a}{1})=2$, yielding the result $a=-10$. Now, if $x+2$ divides $x^3-10x+b$, then we must have that $(-2)^3-10(-2)+b=0$, so we have that $b=-12$.